# When two projections in a C*-algebra are "almost" Murray-von Neumann equivalent, they are equivalent

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra and $p,q \in A$ be projections. Assume there is an element $a\in A$ such that $\|aa^*-p\|<\frac{1}{4}$ and $\|a^*a-q\|<\frac{1}{4}$. Then there is a partial isometry $v$ with $vv^*=p$ and $v^*v=q$.

This is considered obvious in the paper I'm reading. I've tried to mimic the proof of the following proposition.

> Let $p$, $q$ be projections in a C*-algebra A. If $\|p-q\|<1$ then p and q are unitarily 
>   equivalent.

Which involves using a suitable expression ($1-p-q+2pq$) and polar decomposition. But it's not going anywhere.

Comment: Intuitively, maybe we can first show that when $aa^*$ is close to $p$, then the range projection of $aa^*$, denote it by $r_1$, is close to $p$, maybe the assumption is strong enough to imply $||r_1-p||<1$, so they are unitary equivalent, do the same thing for $q$, note that $r_1, r_2$ are unitary equivalent.

Comment: What do you mean by "almost" m-vN equivalent?

Comment: @Squirtle: The condition is made quite explicit above, just not in the title.

Comment: @Squirtle: Projections $ p $ and $ q $ are said to be *almost Murray-von Neumann equivalent* if and only if they are within distance $ \epsilon $ of corresponding elements that are actually Murray-von Neumann equivalent, where $ \epsilon > 0 $ depends on your choice. Setting $ \epsilon = \dfrac{1}{2} $ leads to some interesting consequences, as shown below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One can prove that $p,q$ are Murray -von-Neumann equivalent if they fulfill
$$
\|aa^*-p\|<\frac 12,\quad \|a^*a-q\|<\frac 12.
$$
The proof is standard (for example it is outlined in the comment of @ougao), I was just lucky to find $\|(1/2-p)^{-1}\|=2$.

We first assume that the $C^*$-algebra $A$ is unital.

First note that $(1-2p)^2=1$, hence $(1-2p)$ is its own inverse and $\|1-2p\|=1$. 
It follows that the inverse of $\frac 12-p$ is $2-4p$ and that $\|2-4p\|=2$.
If $\|aa^*-p\|<\frac 12$, then $\|aa^*\|< \frac 32$ and $Spec(aa^*)\subset [0,\frac 32[\subset\Bbb{R}$.
Moreover, since $\frac 12-p$ is invertible and $\|p-aa^*\|<\frac{1}{\|(\frac 12-p)^{-1}\|}$, we have that
$\frac 12-p+p-aa^*=\frac 12-aa^*$ is invertible. This means that the spectrum of $aa^*$ has a gap at $\frac 12$, i.e., 
an open interval around $\frac 12$ which does not intersect $Spec(aa^*)$, since $Spec(aa^*)$ is closed.

Hence there exists an $r\in]0,\frac 12[$ such that 
$$
Spec(aa^*)\subset  B_r(0)\cup B_r(1).
$$
Similarly we find that 
$$
Spec(a^*a)\subset  B_{r_1}(0)\cup B_{r_1}(1),
$$
and we can assume that $r=r_1$.

We define on $D:=(B_{r}(0)\cup B_{r}(1))\cap\Bbb{R}$ the continuous function
$$
f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lr} 0& \text{if $x\in B_r(0)$}\\
1/\sqrt{x}& \text{if $x\in B_r(1)$.}
    \end{array}  \right.
$$
Note that on $D$ the function $xf^2(x)$ is a projection with a distance less than $r$ to the identity function, i.e.,

1. $x^2f^4(x)=xf^2(x)$.
2. $|xf^2(x)-x|\le r$.

Then we apply functional calculus and set $v:= f(aa^*)a$. We have that $vv^*=aa^*f^2(aa^*)$ and moreover, by 1.,
$$
(vv^*)^2=(aa^*)^2f^4(aa^*)=aa^*f^2(aa^*).
$$
Note that for any continuous function $f$ on $D$ we have $a^*f(aa^*)a=a^*af(a^*a)$ (this holds for polynomials and $f$ is the limit of polynomials).

Therefore we have $v^*v=a^*f^2(aa^*)a=a^*af^2(a^*a)$ and so, by 1.,
$$
(v^*v)^2=(a^*a)^2f^4(a^*a)=a^*af^2(a^*a).
$$
So $vv^*$ and $v^*v$ are equivalent projections (they are the range projections of $aa^*$ and $a^*a$ respectively) and we compute
$$
\|vv^*-p\|\le \|vv^*-aa^*\|+\|aa^*-p\|< r+\frac 12<1,
$$
where $\|vv^*-aa^*\|\le r$ follows from 2.

Similarly 
$$
\|v^*v-q\|\le \|v^*v-a^*a\|+\|a^*a-q\|< r+\frac 12<1,
$$
where $\|v^*v-a^*a\|\le r$ follows from 2.

Since $A$ is unital, there are unitary elements $u,s$ with $uvv^*u^*=p$ and $v^*v=sqs^*$. Then
$(uvs)^*uvs=q$ and $uvs(uvs)^*=p$.

Finally we prove the general case. If $A$ is non-unital, embed it into its unitalization $A^\sim$, and there $p$ and $q$ are Murray-von-Neumann equivalent, i.e., there exists $b\in A^\sim$, such that $bb^*=p$ and $b^*b=q$. But then $b=pb$, since $\|(b-pb)(b-pb)^*\|=0$, and so, since $A$ is an ideal in $A^\sim$ we have that $b\in A$, hence $p,q$ are Murray-von-Neumann equivalent in $A$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my own attempt on the problem, which turns out to be essentially San’s argument above (I only realized this when writing my response). I would therefore like to focus on demystifying the continuous functional calculus that takes place in the argument and on making portions of it more transparent. **All credit is due to San, of course, for posting the first solution.** My only goal here is to explain my thought processes to show that the problem yields to a systematic attack and is therefore not exceedingly difficult.

---

We will prove the stronger version of the problem as presented in San’s answer. **We will also relax the condition that $ A $ is unital.**

As all projections have norm $ 1 $, playing around with the Triangle Inequality yields
$$
\| a a^{*} \| = \| a^{*} a \| < \frac{3}{2}.
$$
As $ a a^{*},a^{*} a \in A_{\geq 0} $, we thus have
$$
\sigma(a a^{*}),\sigma(a^{*} a) \subseteq \left[ 0,\dfrac{3}{2} \right).
$$
Sam has already shown that $ \dfrac{1}{2} \notin \sigma(a a^{*}) $ and $ \dfrac{1}{2} \notin \sigma(a^{*} a) $, under the extra assumption that $ A $ is unital. However, we do not have to require that $ A $ is unital, for once we have argued in $ A^{\sim} $ to get $ \dfrac{1}{2} \notin \sigma(a a^{*}) $ and $ \dfrac{1}{2} \notin \sigma(a^{*} a) $, we can switch back to $ A $. The remainder of the argument does not rely on the existence of a unit. However, when applying the continuous functional calculus in the **absence of a unit**, any function introduced must satisfy the property that **its value at $ 0 $ is $ 0 $**.

By a standard Banach-algebra result, we get
$$
\sigma(a a^{*}) \cup \{ 0 \} = \sigma(a^{*} a) \cup \{ 0 \}.
$$
We can thus find an $ r \in \left[ 0,\dfrac{1}{2} \right) $ and an $ s \in \left( \dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{2} \right) $ such that
$$
          \sigma(a a^{*}),\sigma(a^{*} a)
\subseteq D \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} [0,r] \cup \left[ s,\dfrac{3}{2} \right].
$$
Then the function $ f: D \to \Bbb{R} $ defined by
$$
\forall x \in D: \quad
f(x) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $ x \in [0,r] $}, \\
1 & \text{if $ x \in \left[ s,\dfrac{3}{2} \right] $},
\end{cases}
$$
is continuous on both $ \sigma(a a^{*}) $ and $ \sigma(a^{*} a) $. Applying the continuous functional calculus, we have well-defined projections $ f(a a^{*}) $ and $ f(a^{*} a) $, because $ f = f^{*} = f^{2} $. These are called **spectral projections**, and they exist for self-adjoint elements that have a gap in their spectrum.

Now, $ f(a a^{*}) $ and $ f(a^{*} a) $ are Murray-von Neumann equivalent. To prove this, we want to exploit the fact that $ f(a a^{*}) a = a f(a^{*} a) $, as already explained in [this other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234928/why-is-fxx-is-defined-and-xfxx-fxxx/1242274#1242274). Suppose that there is a positive continuous function $ g: D \to \Bbb{R} $ such that $ f(x) = x [g(x)]^{2} $ for all $ x \in D $. If we let
$$
b \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} g(a a^{*}) a,
$$
then
\begin{align}
    b b^{*}
& = [g(a a^{*}) a] [a^{*} \overline{g}(a a^{*})] \\
& = [g(a a^{*}) a] [a^{*} g(a a^{*})] \quad (\text{As $ g $ is positive.}) \\
& = g(a a^{*}) (a a^{*}) g(a a^{*}) \\
& = f(a a^{*}). \quad (\text{As $ g(x) x g(x) = f(x) $ for all $ x \in D $.})
\end{align}
Similarly,
\begin{align}
    b^{*} b
& = [a^{*} \overline{g}(a a^{*})] [g(a a^{*}) a] \\
& = [a^{*} g(a a^{*})] [g(a a^{*}) a] \quad (\text{As $ g $ is positive.}) \\
& = [g(a^{*} a) a^{*}] [a g(a^{*} a)] \\
& = g(a^{*} a) (a^{*} a) g(a^{*} a) \\
& = f(a^{*} a). \quad (\text{As $ g(x) x g(x) = f(x) $ for all $ x \in D $.})
\end{align}
Of course, we still have to find $ g $, and the most natural (in fact, only) choice is
$$
\forall x \in D: \quad
g(x) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
\begin{cases}
0                   & \text{if $ x \in [0,r] $}, \\
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}} & \text{if $ x \in \left[ s,\dfrac{3}{2} \right] $},
\end{cases}
$$
which is the same function exhibited in San’s answer.

Observe next that $ \| p - f(a a^{*}) \| < 1 $. This is because
\begin{align}
       \| p - f(a a^{*}) \|
& \leq \| p - a a^{*} \| + \| a a^{*} - f(a a^{*}) \| \\
& \leq \| p - a a^{*} \| + \| \text{id}|_{D} - f \|_{\infty} \quad
       (\text{By the continuous functional calculus.}) \\
& <    \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \quad
       (\text{Compare the graphs of $ \text{id} $ and $ f $.}) \\
& =    1.
\end{align}
Similarly, $ \| q - f(a^{*} a) \| < 1 $.

Projections that are within distance $ 1 $ of each other are homotopy-equivalent (this is folklore). It is also not hard to show that homotopy equivalence implies Murray-von Neumann equivalence. Therefore,
$$
p \sim f(a a^{*}) \sim f(a^{*} a) \sim q.
$$